# How can I get iTunes to check for new podcast episodes more often?

Tags: itunes, automation, podcasts

I would like for iTunes to check for new podcast episodes more often than it does, without having to click “Refresh” manually. Is this possible?

Comment: To be clear, you mean more frequently than "Every Hour"?  And what OS?

Comment: Is hourly the default? My iTunes hadn’t checked for new episodes despite having recently been awakened from a few days of sleep. On OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard

Comment: I think the default is manual.

Comment: @Mike I think it’s “every day” since I don’t remember changing my preference and that’s what it was set to. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the podcast section in iTunes, on the bottom on the screen there is a *Settings…* button.

[image]

Click that, then make sure you are setting the default settings. Then set the refresh to however often you want.

Beyond that, it depends on your OS. I have created an Automator script to check 4 times per day.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this, though I expected it to be in the main Preferences dialog. Thank you! I appreciate the screenshot, too.